# What does "the eigenvectors of a Hermitian operator are a complete set" mean?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, linear-algebra

I read in my book that the eigenvectors of a Hermitian operator are a complete set.
What does the author mean by that?

Comment: It means they have linearly independent eigenvectors. So they can form a basis for the vector space and are therefore "complete"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your operator acts on a finite vector space (for continuous spaces the question is a bit more difficult to answer). For a vector space of dimension $n$ you need exactly $n$ vectors which are linearly independent. For the matrix representation of your operator this now means that all eigenvectors of that matrix are linearly independent and none of it has eigenvalue zero. In other words the eigenvectors form a basis for the entire vector space the operator acts on. I'm not sure whether one needs to exclude the eigenvalue zero for the complete set but it could lead to trouble when talking about bijections and the question whether the matrix is invertable which is necessary for a linear function to go from the space and cover the entire space in its image (so being complete). The fact that the eigenvalues are real (due to the operator being Hermitian) and that the eigenvectors are orthogonal is a bonus.